# How can I create the YouTube Modal Bottom Sheet with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to have a modal bottom sheet that I can scroll through as normal without closing the modal bottom sheet. Then, when I'm at the top of my list, I want to be able to close the Modal Bottom Sheet with a scroll gesture.

I would like to add the YouTube style modal bottom sheet shown in the video to my app, but unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

This is the link to the video that shows what I mean: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1977Ptq4Sox6WKGQkiTbCH_zydn8Mu05o/view?usp=sharing

This is inside my Profile Screen:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.95,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 10, right: 10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(23),
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 1,
        minChildSize: 0.5,
        maxChildSize: 1,
        expand: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController _scrollController) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 590,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: 
                      Colors.black),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      InteractiveViewer(
                        transformationController:
                            _zoomProfilePictureController,
                        minScale: 1,
                        maxScale: 3,
                        onInteractionEnd: (ScaleEndDetails endDetails) {
                          setState(() {
                            _zoomProfilePictureController.value =
                                Matrix4.identity();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Swiper(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, int imageIndex) {
                            return Hero(
                              tag: "Profile",
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: widget.user.imageUrl[imageIndex],
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                useOldImageOnUrlChange: true,
                                placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    strokeWidth: 3,
                                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                      primaryColor.withOpacity(0.7),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(
                                  Icons.error_outline,
                                  size: 30,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: widget.user.imageUrl.length,
                          pagination: SwiperPagination(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            builder: DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                              size: 8,
                              activeColor: widget.user.imageUrl.length > 1
                                  ? primaryColor
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              activeSize: 10,
                            ),
                          ),
                          control: widget.user.imageUrl.length > 1
                              ? SwiperControl(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 250),
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  disableColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  size: 228,
                                )
                              : null,
                          loop: false,
                        ),
                      ),
```

This is how I call the BottomSheet:

```
                        ListTile(
                        onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return ProfileInformationHomeScreen(
                              secondUser,
                              widget.currentUser,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: you are missing `  isScrollControlled: true,` on calling BottomSheet

Comment: Yes you are right, but this also not gives me the result like in the video I have shared :(

Comment: I accept your answer, but the output of this code, is not like in the video I shared. Nevertheless, I thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm glad , play around with it, you can desing the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's `DraggableScrollableSheet`.

create a widget for bottomSheet.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
        topRight: Radius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        ///* it will be always visible 95% of screen,
        ///* if we drag down at 50% it will close the sheet
        initialChildSize: 0.95,
        minChildSize: 0.5,
        maxChildSize: .95,
        expand: false,

        builder: (BuildContext context, c) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView(
              controller: c,
              children: [
              /// your widgets
```

call a method to `showModalBottomSheet`.

```dart
 _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (context) => DestinationBottomSheetWidget(),
      );
    }
```

To close the buttomSheet you can drag or use a button inside  `DraggableScrollableSheet` builder and use `Navigator.of(context).pop()`.

I do like this and add item of `ListView`

```
  /// heading
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20,
                    
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Title",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                       
                      ),

                      ///* this empty widget will handle the spaces
                      Icon(
                        Icons.close,
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

for more [flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html) [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxdBIwZ4hN8)

Comment: Thank you very much! I try it out now and let you know if it works. :)

Comment: It is nearly perfect! But now I only can dismiss the ModalBottomSheet, when I scroll the top of the ModalBottomSheet. How can I dismiss the ModalBottomSheet by scrolling any where down, when I am on the top of my scroable list?

Comment: yes you can do that, also if you call `Navigator.of(context).pop()` inside `DraggableScrollableSheet` , it wil close

Comment: Would you please explain me this in detail and maybe with an example?

Comment: I guess this is not that what I meant. When you look at the video, there is a list which is displayed in a BottomSheet. When I scroll the list, even if I on top of the list, I am not able to close the BottomSheet (you see this white half circle on top of the list). Only when I take my finger of the display and scroll another time down, I can close the BottomSheet. Do you understand what I mean Yeasin? :/

Comment: check the controller of  `controller: c` also ` minChildSize: 0.5,`

Comment: I added the controller, but this only makes my list scrollable to half of the screen until I can dismiss the BottomSheet :/

Comment: can you add you code or share pastebin link

Answer (score 0):

```
   body: _selectedIndex == 2
      ? SafeArea(
          child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(lastindex),
        )
      : SafeArea(
          child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?